# Análise Estática de Código - Identificar possível divisão por Zero

Tags: .net, análise-estática

Alguém conhece / construiu alguma lógica (regra) de análise estática de código-fonte (para [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) ou [Gendarme](http://mono-project.com/Gendarme)) que busca possíveis brechas no código que incorram em uma divisão por zero?

Ou seja, uma lógica que analise a IL do assembly e critique o primeiro código, porém não o segundo:

```
// (1) Poderá ocorrer erro de divisão por Zero - deve acusar no analisador
   int resultado = numerador / denominador;

// (2) Checkagem antes da divisão - omite crítica
   int resultado;
   if (denominador != 0) 
   {
       resultado = numerador / denominador;
   }
```

Comment: O Code Contracts não é fxcop nem Gendarme, mas detecta esse tipo de coisas.

Answer (score 3):

o Visual Studio consegue a partir da análise sintática e construção do IL descobrir uma possível divisão por 0.

Porém essa análise não assume o "estado" do programa, ou seja, é possível descobrir uma divisão por zero assumindo valores constantes, mas não por um valor que venha de um cálculo variável por exemplo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para prevenir isso, basta você criar um método em uma classe que faça essa divisão e te avise quando estiver debugando seu código..

```
class DivisionTest
{
    public static int Divide(int numerator, int denominator)
    {
        if (denominator == 0)
        {
            // You need check this :/
            Debugger.Break();
        }
        return numerator / denominator;
    }
}
```